# TFS - Can I modify the related work items associated to a check in?

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to modify the work items that associated to a check in after it has been commited?

I made a mistake on one of my check ins

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of starting at the ChangeSet, you need to begin with the Work Items you want to remove or add to a ChangeSet. In order to remove a Work Item from a ChangeSet, do the following:

- Open the Work Item.
- Change to the All Links tab.
- Remove the link for the ChangeSet of the check in.
- Save the Work Item

You can also add links to other changesets on this tab by choosing "Add New Link" and then selecting ChangeSet as the type of link.